# How to find play audio path for iOS application?

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, phonegap

**getMediaURL()** working fine for android application but i did't get audio path for iOS application.

```
function playAudio(sound) {
    var mp3URL = getMediaURL(sound);
    var media = new Media(mp3URL, null, mediaError);
    media.setVolume(1.0);
    media.play();
}

function getMediaURL(sound) {
    if (device.platform.toLowerCase() === "android") { 
        return cordova.file.applicationDirectory.replace('cdvfile://', 
'') + 'www/application/app/' + sound.substr(1); 
    } else { 
        return cordova.file.applicationDirectory.replace('cdvfile://', 
'') + sound.substr(1); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just put your sounds in a folder in www ?

Comment: I don't know that where to put sounds in iOS and how to get path.

Answer (score 0):

Put your sounds in a /www/sounds folder

```
www/sounds/mysound.mp3
```

Then load the sound in JavaScript

```
 var sound = new Audio('/sounds/mysound.mp3');
```